# fmt:formatNumber display negative currency in -$xxx.xx format in JSTL

Tags: jstl, currency

I am using fmt:formatNumber to format currency in JSTL, it will display negative currency in ($100) format, how do I make it display negative currency in negative format instead of ($100)?

thanks very much,

sue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:
`<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" pattern="$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00" value="-10000" />`

You can remove '$' from the pattern, if you like.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will always display '$' as currencySymbol. If you are trying to display the currency en € it will not work.

Comment: well, you can use   pattern="#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"  this will not display the '$' symbol

Answer (score 12):

If you use the pattern attribute and you want to display the currency symbol, then you have to add the currency symbol place holder ( ¤ ) to the pattern itself.
The ¤ will be replaced with the given currencySymbol value.

In the example I show two formats in the pattern attribute. One for positive values and one for negative values. They are separated with the semicolon ';'. Both are using the place holder for the currencySymbol.

Example:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="-10000" type="currency" currencySymbol="$" pattern="¤ #,##0.00;¤ -#,##0.00"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add if u are using type as curreny then currencyCode is required otherwise some random symbol is displayed.
If u dont want to use the currencyCode[it will ldisplay what every u have specified in the currecyCode] then use pattern like

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" pattern="#,##0.00;" value="-10000" />
```